# How do I add a description for a schema (dto) in Swagger for Nestjs?

Tags: swagger, nestjs, openapi, nestjs-swagger

I would like to add a description field to my dto (also to satisfy `no_schema_description` in OpenAPI linting), but find no way to do so. Which decorator to use? At the point of defining the dto or in the response?

Update (clarify): I am looking to define a description for the whole schema, not for single properties.

Comment: This functionality doesn't exist.  There's an open PR adding a class decorator, but it's only adding "name".  I'd recommend you open an issue there, or contribute with a PR if this is something you need.  PR here: https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/pull/983

Comment: @HMilbradt Thanks for the information. I created an issue for this: https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/1596

Answer (score -1):

You can do that simply by using `ApiProperty()`:

```
@ApiProperty({
  description: 'The age of a cat',
})
age: number;
```

I recommend you to check the official doc [openapi/types-and-parameters](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/types-and-parameters)

Comment: That is for documenting the properties that are part of the dto. But OpenAPI also has a description for the complete schema, that is what I am searching for.